# Execute sql query from tab click event

Tags: vb.net

I have a project where I am connecting my database to the windows application in vb.net. I am required to make tabs that sort the data in a specific way. For example, it is a student database with names, etc. So When I press the "Student by Last name" tab, it sorts the data by last name in ascending order. So, I made a query which brought a button, but I don't know how to execute the button automatically when the tab page is clicked. The user can't have the control of sorting. The tab does it itself. Any help will be great! I have been looking everywhere for help.

```
Private Sub TabPage2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbLastName.Click
        TabPage1.Hide() "this is made to get rid of previous page, but may be unnecessary"
        tbLastName.Show() "this is supposed to show the data"
        Sort_By_LastNameToolStripButton.Enabled() "My attempt to execute code from the query button that I made hidden"

    End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code to run the query?  If you want something to run when the user clicks a tab (not very intuitive, IMO) you need the query code in that event.

Answer (score 0):

Try the tab control Selected event to run your database code

Answer (score 0):

Keep a copy of the queried data, and then order it depending on which tab is selected. Use the `TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged` event

```
Private queryData As IEnumerable(Of Student)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    queryData = QueryStudentsFromDatabase()
End Sub

Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case TabControl1.SelectedIndex
        Case 0 ' Last Name
            Dim displayData = queryData.OrderBy(Function(s) s.LastName)
        Case 1 ' Student ID
            Dim displayData = queryData.OrderBy(Function(s) s.ID)
    End Select
    ListView1.DataSource = displayData ' or whatever
End Sub
```

This is a very simple example. In the interest of brevity, it is performing work on the UI thread. You can handle offloading the work if you wish.